# Object turns gray when rendering

Tags: modeling

I made a simple object in Blender but when I go to *Render > Image Render* the object turns gray. I tried a lot of different things but I am using Blender for the first time and don't even know the basics or where different settings are located. Do you have any idea how could I fix this?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have lights (sun) angle 11.4 specular 1.0 strength 1000

[image: settings screenshot]

[image]

Comment: It would help if you could add your blend file to your question so we can see. (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)  But mainly I suspect you need to add a shader to set the color of your object.

Comment: Screenshots would really help. Please [Edit] your questions and use the 'Image' icon to attach images.

Comment: Hwllo and welcome, please add some screenshots to see the issue AND my question for you will be... Did you add any lights to the scene?

Comment: I added more info and included .blend file. Is the question now visible because it says it is closed?

Comment: @Lea add some screenshots of your settings, the issue and verything that you consider useful, the Blend file should be the last resource or support. THe more info you add, the better for your post

Comment: @Lea The object with the "gold" material is duplicated. You have two objects in the exact same space. The one that's called Cube.007 has a gold material, Cube.008 has a light gray material and they are the same objects at the same location. You should delete one of them or move one aside. Nevertheless, without any environment or HDRI for the world background, the object will still look quite flat, because there is nothing to reflect apart from a plain white color around it.

Comment: I see, I removed the object and I included another screenchot. What can I do to make final render look like it does in display render preview?

Comment: As Gordon said....just put e.g. a checker texture before your background in your world shader and choose a red color and you will see "something"

Comment: I don't really know how to do this, I am using Blender for the first time..Is there any way I can add the same 'world' as I can see it in display render preview?

Comment: You need to add an HDRI image to the world background, or use a sky node

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked:)